# .htaccess not working on Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file which works when I try it on my local xampp setup.

Here's the file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^videos/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ videos.php?var=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ video.php?var=$1 [NC,L]
```

But whenever I upload it to my Ubuntu 14.04 VPS running LAMP, the htaccess does not work, as if it is not even there.

I have `Require all granted` in my 000-default.conf, I tried `a2enmod rewrite` and then restarted apache, but still, no development.

BTW, `AccessFileName .htaccess` is uncommented in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Here'es my directory configuration in `000-default.conf`

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /vagrant/www/site/

    <Directory /vagrant/www/site/>
            Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Which version of Apache is your local xampp setup?

Comment: @DarrenCook It is v3.2.1, but that is irrelevant since it works on xampp but not in ubuntu(lamp).

Comment: What version of Apache, is what I meant. Ubunut 14.04 uses Apache 2.4; if your local setup is using Apache 2.2 then there are one set of possible answers, if it is also 2.4 then there are different set of possible answers. :-)

Comment: BTW, 3.2.1 is the cPanel version? See http://xampp.wikia.com/wiki/XAMPP_for_Windows/Versions   (If so, cPanel 3.2.1 always seems to coincide with Apache 2.4.x)

Comment: As suggested by @DarrenCook, Apache 2.2 doesn't accept `Require all granted` statement. Check apache error logs for more details on where it fails.

Comment: @hjpotter92 nope, does not work, I am running apache 2.4

Comment: Make sure you have `AllowOverride` set correctly in your main Apache config

Comment: @acro444 It is set to all